# Styling input element using only CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to style the input element as mentioned below.

[image]

I did this by removing border property and adding border-bottom alone.
But when I am entering text in that, some border is appearing.

[image]

How can I remove the border when the input is focused? Is there any way that we can do it using only CSS (like any pseudo element) without using scripting.

```html
<div><span>First Name</span><span class="spacing" style="
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
"></span><input type="text" style="
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your CSS, set `outline: none;` for `input` elements.

```css
input[type="text"] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    outline: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div><span>First Name</span><span class="spacing" style="
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
"></span><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: thanks.. :) working great.
Any selector that we can use for this scenario..Apart from this I want to change the border-bottom Color when entering text?

Comment: You'll want to use the `:focus` selector.

Comment: @Jayababu I updated the answer.  I moved the input style to CSS and added an attribute selector to narrow it down to text inputs.  Also, added the `:focus` selector to change the `border-color`.